# How to read a large number of LDAP entries in perl?

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

I already have an LDAP script in order to read LDAP user information one by one. My problem is that I am returning all users found in Active Directory. This will not work because currently our AD has around 100,000 users causing the script to crash due to memory limitations.

What I was thinking of doing was to try to process users by batches of X amount of users and if possible, using threads in order to process some users in parallel. The only thing is that I have just started using Perl, so I was wondering if anyone could give me a general idea of how to do this.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the executable `ldapsearch` to work in your environment (and it does work in *nix and Windows, although the syntax is often different), you can try something like this:

```
my $LDAP_SEARCH = "ldapsearch -h $LDAP_SERVER -p $LDAP_PORT -b $BASE -D uid=$LDAP_USERNAME -w $LDAP_PASSWORD -LLL";
my @LDAP_FIELDS = qw(uid mail Manager telephoneNumber CostCenter NTLogin displayName);
open (LDAP, "-|:utf8", "$LDAP_SEARCH \"$FILTER\" " . join(" ", @LDAP_FIELDS));
while (<LDAP>) {
  # process each LDAP response
}
```

I use that to read nearly 100K LDAP entries without memory problems (although it still takes 30 minutes or more).  You'll need to define `$FILTER` (or leave it blank) and of course all the LDAP server/username/password pieces.

If you want/need to do a more pure-Perl version, I've had better luck with `Net::LDAP` instead of `Net::LDAP::Express`, especially for large queries.